# Background image isn't showing in all apps

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I created two apps named admin and student, admin templates hold **base.html** and login.html. I set the background image and navbar in base.html. The background image is stored in `static/admin/image/background.jpg` the same path I gave to set the background for the body tag present inside base.html. Inside the login page I extend the base class and override the content block and the background image shows as well for login.html which is present in the same app. After login, I redirect to the student apps registration.html page which also extends base.html present inside admin but the background image is not shown for students apps on any page and it gives an error in the terminal as`Not Found: /display/static/admin/images/baloon.jpg`. I added the static path to urlpatterns as well but still didn't work

I created two app admins and students under one project. admin template holds base.html,login.html. student holds registration.html and display.html. background image set inside base.html. all other web pages extend base.html. the background image is shown for login.html but not for student apps HTML pages. It gives an error as Not `Found: /registration/static/admin/images/baloon.jpg` on the terminal. static file stored under the main project name as 'static' already mentioned in the settings

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT=BASE_DIR/'static'
STATICFILES_DIRS=(
    BASE_DIR/'staticfiles',
)
```

Comment: Show template code where the image does not work. You have relative URL there.

Comment: I was using the <body style="background-image:url('static/login/images/back.jpg');"> Instead of <body style="background-image:url('/static/login/images/back.jpg');">
slash was missing infront of static

Comment: Consider using Django static files engine: `{% static "login/images/back.jpg" %}`

Answer (score 0):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT=BASE_DIR/'static' # comment this
STATICFILES_DIRS=(
    BASE_DIR/'static',  # correct `static` instead of `staticfiles`
)
```